# Excepciones en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, excepciones

estoy trabjando en un api en node.js tengo una funcion que valida datos y en caso de un error pongo un "Throw new Error". Sucede que cuando se ejecuta la excepcion se muestra en la consola pero en postman (que es donde lo estoy probando) no se muestra la excepcion.

Ejemplo de codigo:

```js
var numero = 3;

if(numero === 2){
   console.log("El numero es 2!!");
}else{
    var mensajeError = {
      "Codigo Error":"E009",
      "Mensaje Error":"El numero no es 2"
    }
    throw new Error(mensajeError); //throw exception
}
```

Comment: haces una excepcion, pero creo que tendriamos que ver todo el servicio

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework como Express o algún otro?

Answer (score 0):

podrias intentar con el clasico:

```
try {
 //codigo 
} catch (err) {
 console.error(err);
}
```

estos son validos en javaScript

Comment: El caso que tiene el OP es correcto. Sin embargo, su pregunta parece que va más orientado a excepciones en servicios web.

Comment: es que no especifica en que, solo coloco un poco de código, no especifica donde lo usara...